# Include header file syntax

Tags: c++, c

Reading various C/C++ codes, I can say that I am confused between these two ways of including a header file inside the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

Some text editors has auto-completion feature. I have been recommended the latter most of the time. But in various examples of programs, using angular braces is also recommended.

Which one should one choose while writing a C/C++ program? What are the differences of the two? Are they language specific?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118376/what-are-the-rules-on-include-xxx-h-vs-include-xxx-h/4118390#4118390

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not language specific. Both C and C++ makes use of them.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

> Both user and system header files are included using the preprocessing
>   directive ‘#include’. It has two variants:
>
> ```
> #include <file>
> ```
>
> This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file
>   named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend
>   directories to this list with the -I option (see Invocation).
>
> ```
> #include "file"
> ```
>
> This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches
>   for a file named file first in the directory containing the current
>   file, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used
>   for `<file>`. You can prepend directories to the list of quote
>   directories with the `-i` quote option. The argument of `#include`,
>   whether delimited with quote marks or angle brackets, behaves like a
>   string constant in that comments are not recognized, and macro names
>   are not expanded. Thus, `#include <x/*y>` specifies inclusion of a
>   system header file named `x/*y`.
>
> However, if backslashes occur within file, they are considered
>   ordinary text characters, not escape characters. None of the character
>   escape sequences appropriate to string constants in C are processed.
>   Thus, `#include "x\n\\y"` specifies a filename containing three
>   backslashes. (Some systems interpret `\` as a pathname separator. All
>   of these also interpret `/` the same way. It is most portable to use
>   only `/`.)
>
> It is an error if there is anything (other than comments) on the line
>   after the file name.

Comment: Several of the details here are specific to some implementations (e.g. under unix) but are not required by the standards.   Implementations on other systems do such things differently.

Comment: The standard actually says nothing about `-I` and current directories and so on, headers are not even required to exist as 'real' files :-) The whole thing is very implementation specific.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html